# Integrating .NET and MSSQL Server, How to create 'scalar, user-defined' functions perched upon state

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I am called upon to deliver some .NET (C#) code for use in MSSQL Server by conforming to the [MS Spec for user defined functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx). This code has to read in a file of state and hang onto it, and then use it to perform the calculations to be exposed as a scalar function. Do I just make a static function that new's the class itself and assigns the result to a private static?

Comment: I don't have any experience on .net based UDFs. However, you can store the state related information in a table & use that inside the UDF to do the calculation.

Comment: Not in this case, not practically. It would slow this thing down to an unusable crawl.

Comment: How frequently will you read the file?  Why can't you store the file in a varbinary column?

Comment: This question is long-obsolete, I don't even remember the circumstances.